# Html encodes & into &amp;

Tags: php, html, laravel, url

I'm using php, laravel 9 framework
I run to a situation where I need to build my URL with parameters that filters the data retrieved from my database :

```
filter(request(['started', 'ended' , 'category', 
          'since' , 'amount', 'date', 'search'
      ]))
```

and the following function is the one to build my URL:

```
public function fullUrlWithQuery(array $query)
{

    $question = $this->getBaseUrl().$this->getPathInfo() === '/' ? '/?' : '?';

    $url = count($this->query()) > 0 ?
          $this->url().$question.Arr::query(array_merge($this->query(), $query))
        : $this->fullUrl().$question.Arr::query($query);
        // ddd($url);
    return ($url) ;
}



public static function query($array)
{
     // replace &amp; with & and return url string 

    return str_replace('&amp;', '&', urldecode(http_build_query($array, '', '&', PHP_QUERY_RFC3986)));
}
```

Up to this point When I debug my URL string in laravel using ddd() it gives the required url string without encoding & into &
however when I pass the URL string into my HTML view :

```
request()->fullUrlWithQuery(['amount'=> 'max' ])
```

The URL on browser encodes again into something like this :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/expenses?amount=max&amp;since=year_ago
```

but what I want in order for my filter function to work properly is this :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/expenses?amount=max&since=year_ago
```

I highly suspect it has something to do with HTML encoding.
my question is, how I can get this done using php ?

thank you for your help, it's highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`route()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-route) helper to generate actual url for named routes. In this example, I presume your url is named `user_expense`.

```
route('user_expense', ['amount' => 'max', 'since' => 'year_ago']);
```

Just make sure you didnt html encode the url in the view, use it this way:

```
<a href="{{ route('user_expense', ['amount' => 'max', 'since' => 'year_ago']) }}">user expense</a>
```

Reusing existing toolkits do cause less future headache in the future.

Comment: I'm not html encoding the url, I tried it your way, it gives the same result encoding the url.